# Using a named alias of an imported module does not work for dot notation of exported names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module

In a React app I have a file with imports like this:

```
import * as cArrayList from './ClassArrayList'
import * as mCalc1 from './moduleCalc1'
```

Then in the same file, I have exports like this:

```
 export const cArrayList.ArrayList
 export const mCalc1.doPreCalculationSetup
 export const mCalc1.doTheCalculations
```

But I get a parsing error: Identifier 'cArrayList' has already been declared.

The MDN docs say in this statement:

```
import * as myModule from '/modules/my-module.js'
```

the "myModule" alias of the module object can be used as a kind of namespace when referring to the imports, to be used as so:

```
 myModule.doAllTheAmazingThings().
```

So why my error?

The only items in this file are 61 import lines and 394 export lines. The whole purpose of this file is to do all the necessary imports just once, creating a namespace holding all the exports available in the project. And then make the individual exports avaiable by reference for all the other modules using them, instead of each module doing another import. This is an experment to avoid a cyclic reference (I think) that causes the program to just loop in the startup phase.

UPDATED

While going through the steps to implement this hack idea of a nameSpace file, I learned some things that made me think that this whole exercise was unnecessary. What I thought was a looping app was really a stalled splash screen with a gif. And even thought the finished hack worked, the many small changes to code that had worked fine before raised questions.  And my late idea to try doing a build and run that was key. That build failed, but identified the failing code for correction. Then there was a series of small code changes to finish up.

So thanks to GIT, I was able to jump back to the point in time where I first saw this problem: a clean compile but a stalled splash screen. Now I ran a build and got this:

```
  Failed to compile.
  Failed to minify the code from this file: 
     ./src/calculations/moduleMoneyPlanEntry.js:53:4
```

The code at that location was simple:

```
function moneyPlanEntry() {
  try {
    process.env.MONEYPLAN = 'development'
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'  (A)
```

The left over line from previous work marked (A) was the problem. Delete that line and all is well. The build runs, and the corrected code runs with the "yarn start" command. So now I will discard my nameSpace hack and continue normally. The key lesson? Run the build once in awhile to check for lurking errors.

Comment: `export const cArrayList.ArrayList` is just syntactically invalid. What is this trying to do?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried refactoring my moduleNameSpace.js file using both answers. Both worked and helped. I found several instances of using an imported variable in the module scope instead of a function scope, like this:
      1. import { Dictionary } from '../moduleNameSpace';
      2. const ownerDetailsDictionary = new Dictionary();
      3. function isCollectionEmpty(collection) {...};
This throws a reference error for Dictionary. This is maybe because of the moduleNameSpace.js file. Maybe that's not needed now, but it works. I wish I could mark both answers as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CertainPerformance already said everything about what's wrong with the syntax.

> The whole purpose of this file is to do all the necessary imports just once, creating a namespace holding all the exports available in the project. And then make the individual exports avaiable by reference for all the other modules using them, instead of each module doing another import.

For that, you'll want to use `export * from '…';` syntax. Or `export { name as alias } from '…';` in case of conflicts.

But it sounds like a really bad idea, going contrary to modularisation by putting everything in a single global namespace. You will no longer have clear dependencies between the parts of your package, but just one big mess.

> This is an experiment to avoid a cyclic reference (I think) that causes the program to just loop in the startup phase.

Circular dependencies usually cause TDZ exceptions, not infinite loops.

Using `const` declarations in your global module will actually make these worse, you really need to use re-exports that actually alias the bindings.

To solve circular dependency issues (and don't want to refactor but keep the dependency structure), you generally need to decide which module should be the entry point to your circle, and in which order the modules should be executed, and then always strictly follow that order in any module import list.

Comment: Your answer works for the module running that code ("moduleNameSpace"). But neither yours or @CertainPerformance's solution solves my higher order problem: the splash screen hangs with a spinning circle. It's a CRA single page app, so I guess I'll write a new question for SO.

Comment: @MartinDuo Yes, to solve the actual problem please ask a new question with a [mre] close to the actual code

Comment: I posted a question and then answered it myself, after researching TDZ exceptions thanks to your mention of it here. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67765747/1993761

Answer (score 1):

`export const <someIdentifier>` will do *two* things:

- Declare a local variable in the module scope named `someIdentifier` (as a `const`)
- Export that as a named export

The error message you're getting is a bit misleading. Whether the variable is declared beforehand or not,

```
export const someObject.someProperty
```

is invalid syntax, because `someObject.someProperty` is not a valid identifier. For similar reasons, you can't do

```
const someObject.someProperty
```

For what you're trying to do, I'd destructure the properties from the imported object when exporting, like so:

```
export const {
  doPreCalculationSetup,
  doTheCalculations
  // you can add more properties here
} =  mCalc1;
```

Demo:

```html
<script type="module">
const obj = { foo: 'foo' };
export const { foo } = obj;
console.log(foo);
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer does seem to work in the module running that code ("moduleNameSpace"). But other modules don't get the import. I'm guessing that the sequence of loading the modules is at fault and the moduleNameSpace file should be loaded and parsed first. But how do I do that?

Comment: Refactor your code to get rid of the circular dependency - how exactly to do this best highly varies depending on the project